# positing in html / css for 100% width divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand the position in html and css by playing around with an example I have made up. In this example what I have created 3 divs which show color blocks. I am trying to make the first 2 blocks span the width of the screen and the third do just sit as it is on screen. I am trying to have all 3 blocks just stacked on top of each other.

in my html i have created 3 classes:

```
    <div class="color-stripred">
    </div>
    
    <div class="color-stripblue">
    </div>
    
    <div class="color-stripgreen">
    </div>
```

In my css i have defined the colors, shapes and positions of these blocks:

```
.color-stripred {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    position: static;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.color-stripblue {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    left: 0;
}

.color-stripgreen {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    left: 0;
}
```

The red block is on top followed by blue then green. It looks like the following picture: [image]

The problem comes when I try and change the positioning in order to make red and box span the width of the screen. i change the red box css as follows:

```
.color-stripred {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

what happens is the redbox spans the width of the screen but the other two boxes shift upwards. how can i stop the blue box and the green box from shifting upwards?

[image]

Comment: `position: fixed` causes your issue. Why are you using it? Also, divs naturally span 100% width of the area they're in.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by `position: fixed;` which you don't even need.

I think what you actually want is to set `body { margin: 0; }`.

According to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_body.asp):

> Most browsers will display the `<body>` element with the following
> default values:
>
> ```
> body {
>   display: block;
>   margin: 8px;
> }
>
> body:focus {
>   outline: none;
> }
> ```

You can see in the snippet below, that if you add this to your CSS (i.e., remove the `margin` from the `body`), all three boxes become full viewport width (even though the `width` is set to `100%`!).

See the snippet below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.color-stripred {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.color-stripblue {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 0;
}

.color-stripgreen {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-stripred"></div>

<div class="color-stripblue"></div>

<div class="color-stripgreen"></div>
```

Comment: ah you are 100% right, so even thought the divs are okay in relation to each other, because they are set within the body then the has to be taken into account too. thanks for that i get i now.

Answer (score 1):

you could add `margin-top:20px;` to `.color-stripblue`

```css
.color-stripred {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.color-stripblue {
  margin-top:20px;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    left: 0;
}

.color-stripgreen {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="color-stripred">
    </div>
    
    <div class="color-stripblue">
    </div>
    
    <div class="color-stripgreen">
    </div>
```